# PHP Прибавить к UNIX 1 месяц?

Tags: php, unix, время

Сейчас я делаю так

```
$time = time() + ((24 * 60 * 60) * 30);
```

Это правильное решение?

Comment: Очевидно, что если в месяце 31 день или 28 - то неправильное.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $time = strtotime("+1 month"); ?>
```